# How to create optionmenu for android 3.0 and higher version and option menu icon not showing in higher version mobiles

Tags: android

How to create optionmenu for Android 3.0 and higher version mobiles?

I am trying to create options menu in my Android program. I am using the following code to inflate options menu. option menu icon not showing in higher version mobiles..

```
public class MainScreenTab extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

private String[] tabs = { "Merchants", "Personal Payee" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_tab_layout);

        //Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
            .setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu); //inflate our menu
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        // switch(item.getItemId()) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.item_refresh) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainScreenTab.this,ListMerchantType.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.item_save) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainScreenTab.this,ListPayee.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with respect to the view?

Comment: option menu icon not showing in higher version mobiles..

Comment: Will provide you the answer that you need to add in your `OnCreate` method

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use this `Reflection` method to force your icon in the `ActionBar`

```
  public static void forceOverFlowIconInActionBar(Activity mActivity)
{

    try
    {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(mActivity);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null)
        {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please accept this as `Answer` if you feel it has served your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. `import java.lang.reflect.Field;` And on your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method just simply add:

```
if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")) {
     try {
          Field field = menu.getClass().getDeclaredField("mOptionalIconsVisible");
          field.setAccessible(true);
          field.setBoolean(menu, true);
     } catch (Exception ignored) {
          ignored.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

and don't forget to add this to your xml menu `android:icon="@drawable/blah_blah"` . Hope it helps. And don't forget to up-vote if it is helpful.

Answer (score -2):

`Menus:` Generally a list of commands or facilities displayed on screen. It is a common user interface for the user. If you want to provide a familiar and consistent user experience you should use Menus in your activity. It is beginning with android 3.0(Api level 11).  So design and user experience my change for device to device that is depends on the Menu apis.

There mainly there menus in the android. Those are Options menu, Context menu, Popup Menu.

```
Options menu:
```

Options menu is a collection of menu items for an activity. The place where you locate icons that is very impact to the app. Such menu items are search, settings, compose email.

If you are developing the options menu for Android 2.3 and lower user can reveal the options menu by pressing menu button. On the 3.0 and higher the options menu items as a combination of action bar items.  Beginning with Android 3.0, the Menu button is deprecated (some devices don't have one), so you should migrate toward using the action bar to provide access to actions and other options.

```
Creating Options Menu in android
```

Simply options menu is where you should you include options and other actions what are relevant to activity. The item in the options menu is depends on the version you are using.
If it is below 3.0 that comes when you press the menu buttons. If it is higher that will comes to the top of the screen. Means that will include with the action bar screen.

You can declare items for the options menu from either your Activity subclass or a Fragment subclass. At one time if you declare both the items in the activity then that will appear one followed another. You can also reorder the menu items in the android:orderInCategory attribute in each you need to move.

To specify a menu item in the activity first you need to override one method. That method is onCreateOptionsMenu() . This mehtod fragments provide their own onCreateOptionsMenu() callback.

```
Example:

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
   return true;
}
```

We can perform add and retrieve options in the menu item api by using  add() and  findItem().
Handling click events in onCreateOptionsMenu():
If you want to provide a click event on the menu items the system calls onOptionsItemSelected. In that method you can identify which item you are selected by using item.getItemId(). which returns the unique ID for the menu item (defined by the android:id attribute in the menu resource or with an integer given to the add() method). You it is matched you can perform your action whatever you want.

Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // Handle item selection
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.new_game:
           newGame();
           return true;
       case R.id.help:
           showHelp();
           return true;
       default:
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

When you successfully handle the menu item that will returns true. If not handle that item that will you should call the superclass implementation of onOptionsItemSelected().
Changing menu items at runtime:
When you call onCreateOptionsMenu() that is displaying simple onCreateOptionsMenu(). you can not change the items in the run time. If you want to change the items in the run time you need to call  onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This method passes you the Menu object as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items.

Example Project:

Open your eclipse and create one project name called OptionsMenu.
In that open you menu folder in the resource folder. In the main.xml file add how many items you want. You can get main.xml file below.

Main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings" android:orderInCategory="100"   
   android:showAsAction="never" android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
   <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Tutorial 1"></item>
   <item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="Tutorial 2"></item>
   <item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="Tutorial 3"></item>
   <item android:id="@+id/item4" android:title="Tutorial 4"></item>
   <item android:id="@+id/item5" android:title="Tutorial 5"></item>
</menu>
```

Here i used @string/menu_settings so you can add that item in the strings.xml file.

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <string name="app_name">OptionsMenu</string>
   <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
   <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

Once that is done open your main activity. In that write the onCreateOptionsMenu method for adding the menu item to the activity. Once that is done if you want to give click events you write onOptionsItemSelected. You can get the complete code below.

MainActivity

```
package com.tutorialindustry.optionsmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.item1:
         Toast.makeText(this, "Tutorial 1 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return true;
       case R.id.item2:
         Toast.makeText(this, "Tutorial 2 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return true;
       case R.id.item3:
         Toast.makeText(this, "Tutorial 3 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return true;           
       case R.id.item4:
         Toast.makeText(this, "Tutorial 4 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return true;
       case R.id.item5:
         Toast.makeText(this, "Tutorial 5 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return true;          
       default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
}
```

Once that is done run you project that you can get the below output. In this way we can perform options menu in the android.